# Combining the outputs of multiple models into one model

Tags: classification, keras, conv-neural-network

I am currently looking for a way i can combine the output of multiple model into one model, I need to create a CNN network that does classification.

[image]

The image is separated into sections  (as seen by the colors),  each section is given as input to a certain model (1,2,3,4) the structure of each model is the same, but each section is given to a separate model to ensure that the the same weight is not applied on whole image - My attempt to avoid full weight sharing, and keeping the weight sharing local.  Each model then perform convolution and max pooling, and generate some sort of output that has to fed into a dense layer that takes the outputs from the prior models (model 1,2,3,4,) and performs classifications.

My question here is it possible to create model 1,2,3,4 and connect it to the fully connected layer and train all the models given the input sections and and the output class - without having to define the outputs of the convolution and pooling layer in keras?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can create such models using Multi-input and multi-output models, refer keras [documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) for more details. Here I am sharing code sample, hope this helps

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Activation, Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Input, Merge, Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D

# Generate dummy data
train1 = np.random.random((100, 100, 100, 3))
train2 = np.random.random((100, 100, 100, 3))
train3 = np.random.random((100, 100, 100, 3))
train4 = np.random.random((100, 100, 100, 3))

y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(np.random.randint(10, size=(100, 1)), num_classes=10)

#parallel ip for different sections of image
inp1 = Input(shape=train1.shape[1:])
inp2 = Input(shape=train2.shape[1:])
inp3 = Input(shape=train3.shape[1:])
inp4 = Input(shape=train4.shape[1:])

# paralle conv and pool layer which process each section of input independently
conv1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(inp1)
conv2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(inp2)
conv3 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(inp3)
conv4 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(inp4)

maxp1 = MaxPooling2D((3, 3))(conv1)
maxp2 =MaxPooling2D((3, 3))(conv2)
maxp3 =MaxPooling2D((3, 3))(conv3)
maxp4 =MaxPooling2D((3, 3))(conv4)

# can add multiple parallel conv, pool layes to reduce size

flt1 = Flatten()(maxp1)
flt2 = Flatten()(maxp2)
flt3 = Flatten()(maxp3)
flt4 = Flatten()(maxp4)

mrg = Merge(mode='concat')([flt1,flt2,flt3,flt4])

dense = Dense(256, activation='relu')(mrg)

op = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(dense)

model = Model(input=[inp1, inp2, inp3, inp4], output=op)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit([train1,train2,train3,train4], y_train,
          nb_epoch=10, batch_size=28)
```